# ArgumentCountError Too few arguments to function Laravel unable to pull data from db and display

Tags: php, laravel

I am working in Laravel 7, pulling data from my db and showing the student his/her score on the scores page in percentage via the following codes.
In my StudentOperationController.php

```
public function show_result($id) {
        $data['result_info'] = Oex_result::where('id', $id)->get()->first();
        $data['student_info'] = Oex_students::select(['oex_students.*', 'oex_exam_masters.title', 'oex_exam_masters.exam_date'])->join('oex_exam_masters', 'oex_students.exam', '=', 'oex_exam_masters.id')->where('oex_students.id', Session::get('id'))->get()->first();
        return view('student.show_result', $data);
    }
```

and in my show_result.blade.php

```
<h2>Result Information</h2>
   <table class="table">
         <tr>
             <td>Number Correct</td>
             <td>{{ $result_info->yes_ans }}</td>
          </tr>
           <tr>
              <td>Number Incorrect</td>
              <td>{{ $result_info->no_ans }}</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
              <td>Total</td>
              <td>{{ round($result_info->yes_ans / ($result_info->yes_ans + $result_info->no_ans) * 100 , 1) }} %</td>
            </tr>
          </table>
```

The reason I show this is that it works as expected. this is within the students dashboard. In my admin, I am trying to do the same thing and show that students data for his/her exam result. In my database, I have a json type data for example: `{"2":"YES","3":"YES","8":"YES"}`. I am still learning Laravel and am stuck on how to get this data to my admin. I am clearly doing something wrong and am in need of assistance. Here is what I have tried:
AdminController.php

```
public function manage_students($id)
    {
        $data['result_info'] = Oex_result::where('id', $id)->get()->first();
        // dd($data);
        $data['student_info'] = Oex_students::select(['oex_students.*', 'oex_exam_masters.title', 'oex_exam_masters.exam_date'])->join('oex_exam_masters', 'oex_students.exam', '=', 'oex_exam_masters.id')->where('oex_students.id', Session::get('id'))->get()->first();
        $data['exams'] = Oex_exam_master::where('status', '1')->get()->toArray();
        $data['students'] = Oex_students::select(['oex_students.*', 'oex_exam_masters.title as exam_name'])
            ->join('oex_exam_masters', 'oex_students.exam', '=', 'oex_exam_masters.id')
            ->get()->toArray();

        return view('admin.manage_students', $data);
    }
```

and in my manage_students.blade.php, I have

```
<tbody>
   @foreach($students as $key => $student)
   <tr>
     <td>{{ $key+1 }}</td>
     <td>{{ $student['name'] }}</td>
     <td>{{ $student['email'] }}</td>
     <td>{{ $student['mobile_no'] }}</td>
     <td>{{ $student['exam_name'] }}</td>
     {{-- <td>N/A</td> --}}
     <td>{{ round($result_info->yes_ans / ($result_info->yes_ans + $result_info->no_ans) * 100 , 1) }} % </td>
     @if($student['status']== 1)
         <td><input data-id="{{ $student['id'] }}" class="student_status" type="checkbox" name="status" checked></td>
     @else
         <td><input data-id="{{ $student['id'] }}" class="student_status" type="checkbox" name="status"></td>
     @endif
         <td>
           <a href="{{ url('admin/edit_student/'. $student['id']) }}" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Edit</a>
           <a href="{{ url('admin/delete_student/' . $student['id']) }}" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Delete</a>
          </td>
        </tr>
     @endforeach
</tbody>
```

In doing this I get the error `Too Few arguments to function ...  0 passed and exactly 1 expected`
I am unable to replicate what I have for the student dashboard and because of my lack of Laravel knowledge, I am having trouble solving this issue. So, any help would be greatly appreciated. If I am missing anything, please let me know so I can edit my question. Thanks in advance.

Edit: manage_students route:

```
Route::get('admin/manage_students', 'AdminController@manage_students');
```

Edit Number 2:

```
Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\AdminController::manage_students(), 0 passed and exactly 1 expected
C:\laragon\www\lionsfieldtest\app\Http\Controllers\AdminController.php:146
```

Referring to this line:

```
 public function manage_students($id)
```

Edit Number 3:
in resources/views/layouts/app.blade.php

```
<li class="nav-item">
   <a href="{{ url('admin/manage_students') }}" class="nav-link">
     <i class="nav-icon fas fa-school"></i>
   <p>
      Student Management
   </p>
  </a>
</li>
```

Edit number 4:
[image: Image showing exam data from various students]
The manage_student page brings in data from a number of student's exam results

Comment: @lagbox Thank you. I edited my question to include the entire error.

Comment: the id of the oex_result table which in this case id oex_result->id = 2

Comment: where are you expecting that to come from? as there is no route parameter defined for that route

Comment: Yes and this is exactly where I am stuck. If I add the /{id} to the route, the whole page gives a 404, so, like I said, my inexperience isn't helping

Comment: I am pulling the route from web.php admin/manage_students' , 'AdminController@manage_students'
Is it possible to create another route and call it within this same @foreach loop within the manage_students.blade.php file?

Comment: @lagbox I have edited my question to show where the route originally comes from.

Comment: I was trying to get the result data that cooresponds with the user who took the exam in the results table which holds the following tables: 'exam_id',
        'question_id',
        'yes_ans',
        'no_ans',
        'result_json'
via:  $data['result_info'] = Oex_result::where('id', $id)->get()->first();
        dd($data);

Comment: so how can you get that result id in the layout to pass via the link? if you can figure that out you can generate a link that would have the id in it and you can adjust your route to take a parameter for it

Comment: I'll see what I can come up with and keep you posted. Thanks @lagbox.

Answer (score 0):

This function request $id;

`public function manage_students($id)`

This route doesn't pass one

`Route::get('admin/manage_students', 'AdminController@manage_students');`

As I can see you are filtering by results which in this case you need $result id

`Route::get('admin/manage_student/{id}', 'AdminController@manage_students');`

So you have to pass result ID, but lets assume there is a default results id

`public function manage_students($id=2)`

then this route works because $id is optional/predefined.
`Route::get('admin/manage_students', 'AdminController@manage_students');`

And if you pass an ID it will use

`Route::get('admin/manage_student/{id}', 'AdminController@manage_students');`

---

Make 2 routes and make parameter optional/predefined.

if you go to /admin/manage_student it will use ID 2
but if you pass /admin/manage_student/5 it will use 5